# In UserMailer, is there a way to set a global rule for when emails should get sent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My UserMailer has several different mailer methods. Before each mailer, is there a DRY way to run a check to determine if the mailer should continue?

Basically I want to do a check to see if the user is on the site. if they are on the site NOT email, I'd like to do this for all user_mailers versus for each one.

Ideas? Thanks

Comment: On the site, meaning, they're currently logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Interceptor to do whatever modifications you need to do. First, define the interceptor in `config/initializers`:

```
class MailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    # bend the message to your will...
  end
end
```

And then register it (you can do it in the same file)

```
ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(MailInterceptor)
```

Comment: For more info on how to use interceptors, see this RailsCast (near the  end) http://asciicasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3